# Updating an iteration during the loop - Python

Tags: python

I'm attempting to update an iteration so that I don't create the duplicates I created with an earlier version of the following.

The  first method is the updated helper method for a generator function that is attempting to yield the terms of the following sequence:

2, 12, 1112, 3112, 132112

I am attempting to 'update' the iterator if it has already gone through the index value but I can't find a good way to do so. What are some methods or built-in functions I could leverage to accomplish this?

```
    def count_seq_helper(target_string):
    """
    helper function
    :param target_string:
    :return:
    """

    result_list = []

    position = 0
    while position < len(target_string) - 1:
        pos = 0
        for i in range(pos, len(target_string)):
            count = 1
            if target_string[pos] == target_string[pos + 1]:
                count += 1

            result_list.append(str(count))
            result_list.append(target_string[i])
    return ''.join(result_list)
```

This was my original code:

```
def count_seq_helper(target_string):
    """
    helper function
    :param target_string:
    :return:
    """

    result_list = []

    for i in range(len(target_string)):
        count = 1
        for j in range(i+1, len(target_string)):
            if target_string[i] == target_string[j]:
                count += 1

        result_list.append(str(count))
        result_list.append(target_string[i])
    return ''.join(result_list)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  But your loop is `while position < len(target_string) - 1`, but then within the loop you never modify either `position` or `target_string`.  Is your `pos` supposed to be `position`?

Comment: What is the desired output and what are you having trouble with? Unable to understand based on your question. It needs further clarification.

Comment: @FrankYellin Thank you for your response. I was able to fix this by using for loop with nested if-elif-else conditionals since there were three conditions I needed to account for. I removed the while loop from there, thank you for your input.

Comment: @FrankYellin & Joe Ferndz Thank you for your responses. I was able to fix this by using for loop with nested if-elif-else conditionals since there were three conditions I needed to account for. I removed the while loop from there, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by leveraging the following pseudocode:

```
for every item in the string:
   if it's the first item:
        while the next item is not equivalent to the last item:
              count the items if they're equivalent and add them to a result list
    
   elif it's not the first item or the last item and it hasn't been previously counted:
        count the items that are equivalent and continues and add them to the result list
    
   else:
        this must be the last item and simply add '21' to the result list

return the result list to the caller function
```